# How can I check a word is already all uppercase?

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to check if a word is already all uppercase. And it might also include numbers.

Example:

```
GO234 => yes
Go234 => no
```

Comment: I don't know ruby, but I'm sure there is something like `ToUpper`. The check the actual string against this function.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can compare the string with the same string but in uppercase:

```
'go234' == 'go234'.upcase  #=> false
'GO234' == 'GO234'.upcase  #=> true
```

Comment: This only works for ASCII. From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-upcase): "The operation is locale insensitive—only characters “a” to “z” are affected. Note: case replacement is effective only in ASCII region.".

Comment: For not ASCII try .mb_chars, for example: 'ТАК' == 'так'.mb_chars.upcase.to_s

Comment: short and smart solution

Answer (score 28):

```
a = "Go234"
a.match(/\p{Lower}/) # => #<MatchData "o">

b = "GO234"
b.match(/\p{Lower}/) # => nil

c = "123"
c.match(/\p{Lower}/) # => nil

d = "µ"
d.match(/\p{Lower}/) # => #<MatchData "µ">
```

So when the match result is nil, it is in uppercase already, else something is in lowercase.

Thank you @mu is too short mentioned that we should use /\p{Lower}/ instead to match non-English lower case letters.

Comment: Although I suspect this will quickly break on non-English alphabets... do ruby REs have any more Unicode-specific support?

Comment: I don't think there would be problem as it just matches lower case a to z. I had a quick test in my irb (ruby 1.9.2 p270) and it works fine :)

Comment: You'd probably want `/\p{Lower}/` with 1.9. Compare `'µ'.match(/[a-z]/)` and `'µ'.match(/\p{Lower}/)` for example.

Comment: That ([a-z]) assumes that only the a-z characters can be lowercase (e.g. English Alphabet), but not something like щ (lower-case for Russian Щ).

Comment: Best to use the [Unicode properties](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) for this sort of thing.

Comment: Then I found that `"щ".upcase == "щ"` instead of `"щ".upcase == "Щ"`. Is there any reason?

Comment: +1 for learning your lesson and getting it right for posterity. The `upcase` method only works for ASCII: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-upcase

Answer (score 4):

I am using the solution by @PeterWong and it works great as long as the string you're checking against doesn't contain any special characters (as pointed out in the comments).

However if you want to use it for strings like "Überall", just add this slight modification:

```
utf_pattern = Regexp.new("\\p{Lower}".force_encoding("UTF-8"))

a = "Go234"
a.match(utf_pattern) # => #<MatchData "o">

b = "GO234"
b.match(utf_pattern) # => nil

b = "ÜÖ234"
b.match(utf_pattern) # => nil

b = "Über234"
b.match(utf_pattern) # => #<MatchData "b">
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

You could either compare the string and string.upcase for equality (as shown by JCorc..)

```
irb(main):007:0> str = "Go234"
=> "Go234"
irb(main):008:0> str == str.upcase
=> false
```

OR

you could call arg.upcase! and check for nil. (But this will modify the original argument, so you may have to create a copy)

```
irb(main):001:0> "GO234".upcase!
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> "Go234".upcase!
=> "GO234"
```

Update: If you want this to work for unicode.. (multi-byte), then string#upcase won't work, you'd need the unicode-util gem mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910573)

Comment: Wrong, the `upcase` method only works for ASCII so it will miss lower case letters such as µ (Greek) and щ (Cyrillic).

Comment: @muistooshort - updated. The poster gave no indication that he wanted this to work for unicode. So assumed the simplest case... anyways updated!