# Ruby: how to tell if character is upper/lowercase

Tags: ruby

I'm ashamed to ask this, because it seems like it ought to be obvious, but how does one tell whether a given character in a string is upper or lowercase in Ruby? I see no obvious canned solution in the `String` class.

I've resorted to the following, which does not consider non-ASCII codes:

```
def is_lower?(c)
  c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'
end

def is_upper?(c)
  ! is_lower(c)
end
```

Something else I've considered is:

```
def is_lower?(c)
    c != c.upcase
end
```

Is there something more idiomatic for this?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8529619/130641) which describes a way to do this that should be Unicode-aware.

Comment: Remember there's a lot more letters than `a` through `z`!

Comment: @tadman- I did indicate that it does not consider non-ASCII codes.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use a regex pattern: [A-Z] or:

```
/[[:upper:]]/.match(c)
```

Comment: This could also be added as a method in `String` with: `class String def upper? !!match(/^[[:upper:]]+$/) end end` (apologies for lack of formatting... comments are limited that way, AFAICT)

Answer (score 35):

I don't think there is something more idiomatic. The only thing you could do -- instead of passing in the string as an argument -- is monkey patch the `String` class:

```
class String
  def is_upper?
    self == self.upcase
  end

  def is_lower?
    self == self.downcase
  end
end

"a".is_upper? #=> false
"A".is_upper? #=> true
```

Using the method in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529619/84631) suggested by the commenter above and monkey patching `String`, you could do this:

```
class String
  def is_upper?
    !!self.match(/\p{Upper}/)
  end

  def is_lower?
    !!self.match(/\p{Lower}/)
    # or: !self.is_upper?
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm still shocked that Ruby, which seems to provide a method/hook for everything, does not offer this common method out of the box!

Comment: @CaffeineComa: Ruby tries very hard to do the right thing. In this particular case, though, it is not obvious what the right thing is, therefore Ruby doesn't do it. For example: what should your two methods return for a character which is neither upper case nor lower case? Or for a character which in some languages is considered upper case and in some languages is considered lower case?

Comment: Note also `self` is not needed in the second solution, you could simply do `!!match(/\p{Upper})`, but maybe that's not as clear to some. If you are working with ActiveSupport it's also cleaner in my opinion to use `match(/\p{Upper}/).present?`

Comment: I'd recommend using `self != self.downcase` and `self != self.upcase` for `is_upper?` and `is_lower?`, respectively, because `'?'.upcase == '?'`

Comment: @Piccolo: I agree with your identification of the shortcomings of just testing `self == self.upcase`, however I'd argue that the character-class checks (`!!match(/^[[:upper:]]+$/)` or, closer to what's here, `!!match(/^\p{Upper}+$/)`) are better, because they'll deal with a whole lot more such potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 8):

Just use an if statement, e.g. `if c == c.upcase` or `if c == c.downcase`.

Comment: `"-".upcase == "-"` is true

Answer (score 7):

What does it mean for a string to be lower case?  Does it mean that the string only contains lower case characters or that it doesn't contain any upper case characters?  In my case I want:

```rb
"a2".is_lower? #=> true
```

..which leads me to:

```
class String

  def is_upper?
    not self.match /[[:lower:]]/
  end

  def is_lower?
    not self.match /[[:upper:]]/
  end

end
```

Note that `/\p{Lower}/` might be better but is unsupported on Ruby 1.8.

Comment: That "not lower"/"not upper" logic makes much sense for your context; thanks for this.  (I'd initially looked at this and overlooked the presence of the `not`, and was finding this flawed, but then I looked closer, and... yeah, this'll do!)

Answer (score 5):

Matching a conversion doesn't emulate the functionality of the libc `isupper()` and `islower()` functions in that both should return `false` for non alpha.

Ranges seem the easiest way to do this for single characters.

```
class String
  def islower?
    return false if self.size > 1
    ('a'..'z').include? self
  end

  def isupper?
    return false if self.size > 1
    ('A'..'Z').include? self
  end
end
```

Comment: This works only for ASCII characters, whereas this question already has several answers that work well for non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Of course, I had a specific requirement to strictly emulate the isupper() and islower() C function so I though this might match better scenarios for others where this strict compliance is required.

Comment: Fair enough. __dummy_text__

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to verify if a character is uppercase or lowercase:

```
#Can be any character
char = 'a'
if char === char.capitalize then
  return 'Character is uppercase.'
else
  return 'Character is lowercase.'
end
```

This very simplistic `if loop` can determine the 'case' of a letter, by checking if it is equal to it's uppercase form. If it's already uppercase, it'll obviously be `true`.

Comment: if loop ? Why not use a begin switch ?

Comment: Leaving aside whether this is the easiest way or not, I think it's worth pointing out that isn't necessarily getting the "right answer" -- because it'll treat all non-alphabetic characters as uppercase, when really, they're considered to be something else.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the other solutions here focus on using strings. I use ruby character ordinal values to process only a single character and avoid strings.

```
def is_lowercase_letter? (x)
  code = x.ord
  97 <= code && code <= 122
end
```

Uppercase is 65 to 90.

Using `'A'.ord` would not rely on you getting the numbers correct and help novice programmers understand what is happening but does not look as clean.

Comment: This only works for ASCII, for example `is_lowercase_letter?('ā') => false`, when it should be `true`.

Comment: @ Niel Stockbridge: Yes. This solution is not realistic once we move beyond ASCII. Example see: `puts 'ă'.ord(); puts 'Ă'.ord(); puts 'ă'.upcase().ord()`.