# Detect if all letters are lower case

Tags: ruby, string

How to detect in Ruby if a sentence has all lower case letters? Likewise, how to detect if a sentence has all uppercase letters?

You can assume this is an English sentence with no foreign characters.

Simple question, I know. Please excuse brevity.

Comment: Based on the possible duplicate, please tell us what you've done so far next time!

Answer (score 2):

`'string' == 'string'.downcase`

If the string is equal to the string with all letters lowercased, then all letters are lowercased.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547694/in-ruby-how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-input-is-in-uppercase-or-lowercase) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529595/how-can-i-check-a-word-is-already-all-uppercase-in-ruby).