# How do I randomly select a name from an array and check if it's uppercase

Tags: ruby

I need to randomly pick a name from an array in Ruby and then check if it uppercase. So far I have:

```
def namegenerator
  return @name.sample
end

def namechecker
  if name.upcase then
    check = TRUE
  else
    check = FALSE
  end
end
```

It needs to be as two separate methods like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check a word is already all uppercase in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529595/how-can-i-check-a-word-is-already-all-uppercase-in-ruby)

Comment: Try this: `arr.sample.then { |word| word == word.upcase }`. See [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-then) (aka `yield_self`).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code example doesn't show a genuine attempt to solve the problem, it's only an outline of the code. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
def sample_word(words)
  words.sample
end

def upcase?(word)
  word == word.upcase
end
```

And then something like:

```
words = %w[APPLE banana CherRy GRAPE]

word = sample_word(words)
puts word # e.g. BANANA
puts upcase?(word) # will print true
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
class NameGenerator
    def initialize(size, items)
        @name = ""
        @size = size
        @items = items
    end

    def namegenerator
        @name = @items.sample(@size).to_s
    end

    def namechecker?
        @name == @name.upcase
    end

    def name 
        @name
    end
end

ng = NameGenerator.new 1, ["name", "Name", "NAME"]
ng.namegenerator

puts ng.name, ng.namechecker?
```

**Update**

I've posted code without much thinking about abstraction and i think it would be much better to encapsulate name and upper case check to separate class and make it immutable, then make generator class that selects one entity from collection.

```
class NameGenerator
    def initialize(items)
        @items = items
    end

    def next
        @items.sample
    end
end

class Name 
    attr_reader :name

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end  

    def is_uppercase?
        @name.match(/\p{Lower}/) == nil
    end
end 

ng = NameGenerator.new [
    Name.new("name"),
    Name.new("Name"),
    Name.new("NAME"),
    Name.new("na-me")
]

name = ng.next
puts name.name, name.is_uppercase?
```

Comment: You're generating random strings not names, besides OP wants randomly picked names from an array. `@chars` doesn't change and is the same for each instance of the class, are you sure it should be an instance variable ?

Comment: Reason it's written like this is that chars or names could be initialized in constructor.

Comment: This reminds me of the story about the sledgehammer and the fly.

Comment: I am not ruby developer, is this too much of code for such a simple task :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check just the first letter:

```
names = %w(Kirk mccoy scott Spock)

names.sample.then { |name| [name, name[0] == name[0].upcase] }
#=> ["mccoy", false]
```